# Make one var-args method call another but with additional arguments

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

This is fine:

```
void print(char *pstrFormat, ...)
{
    va_list vaList;

    va_start(vaList, pstrFormat);

    print(pstrFormat, vaList);

    va_end(vaList);
}

void print(char *pstrFormat, va_list vaList)
{
 ...
}
```

But now I want to add something like:

```
void printError(Error &e,char *pstrFormat,...)
{
 print("Error %s [%d] (%s)",e.name(),e.code(),pstrFormat,...);
}
```

I can't see how to... even if printError calls `print(char *pstrFormat, va_list vaList)` it would need to add additional arguments to the list. I'm effectively trying to combine two `va_lists`, I guess.

Is this possible or do I need to build strings up separately first and pass them to one call of `print(...)`?

Answer (score 4):

With variadic template, you may do something like

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void printError(Error &e, const char *pstrFormat, Ts&&... args)
{
    print("Error %s [%d] (", e.name(), e.code());
    print(pstrFormat, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    print(")");
}
```